# How to search the numerical range where a given numerical digit lies in between?

Tags: python, perl

I have two files

#### file1

SNP data consisting of a chromosome and its position (approximately 400,000 entries)

```
chr pos
a1 456
a2 789
 . .
 . . 
so on
```

#### file2

GTF data consisting of chromosome, position_start, position_end, and details (approximately 500,000 entries)

```
chr pos_start pos_end detail
a1 100 400 gene1
a1 401 700 gene2
a2 200 500 gene3
a2 501 900 gene4
 . .
 . . 
so on
```

#### Desired result

```
chr pos chr pos_start pos_end detail
a1 456 a1 401 700 gene2
a2 789 a2 501 900 gene4
```

I am getting this result using shell script:

```
(grep "$chr" file2.gtf | awk '{if($2 <= '$pos' && $3 >= '$pos') print $0}')
```

in a while loop, but it takes too much time to process all digits in `file1`.

Does anyone know a more efficient way in shell, Python, or Perl to accomplish this?

Comment: I am not familiar with shell. Do you need to compare every entry in file2 with every entry in file1 or do you only need to compare the ones, where `chr` match?

Comment: There is file1 which have chromosome_ID (chr) and a position (pos). So here I am trying to find this position from file2 in range of position_start - position_end and chromosome_ID (chr). Each entry in file1 (chr and pos) need to be compare once in file2.

Comment: Are they in the same order?  Each file has all the `a1` entries, then all the `a2` entries and so on?

Comment: Do your files have those header lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a perl version. Basic idea is that it caches the gtf data into a hash table, and then for each line in the snp file, it only looks at gtf entries that match that chromosome.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use autodie;

my $snp_file = "file1.txt";
my $gtf_file = "file2.txt";

# Read the gtf data into a hash of arrays
my %gtf;
open my $file, "<", $gtf_file;
my $hdr = <$file>; # Discard header line
while (<$file>) {
  chomp;
  my @cols = split /\s+/;
  push @{$gtf{$cols[0]}}, \@cols;
}
close $file;

open $file, "<", $snp_file;
$hdr = <$file>; # Discard header line
say "chr\tpos\tchr\tstart\tend\tdetail";
# Read the snp data
$" = "\t"; # Use tab for array element separator
while (<$file>) {
  chomp;
  my ($chr, $pos) = split /\s+/;
  # Look up all matches of this chromosome in the gtf hash and filter just
  # the ones where pos is in range.
  my @matches = grep { $pos >= $_->[1] && $pos <= $_->[2] } @{$gtf{$chr}};
  # And print them out.
  for my $match (@matches) {
    say "$chr\t$pos\t@$match";
  }
}
close $file;
```

Another option, which I would pursue if you're going to be doing a lot with this data, is loading it all into sqlite or another database and looking up results using SQL. That way you don't have to keep reading the data files; you just look up things in a pre-populated table (with appropriate indexes to make things efficient).

Comment: Perl script worked well. It processed all 4.5lacs entries in 16 minutes.

Comment: @aksg24 Are these data files publicly available? I'm curious to see if I can make it faster.

Comment: @Shown, Sorry, these files are not publicly available. You can make similar data from following publicly available files for file 1 (ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/VCF/GATK/All_20180418.vcf.gz) and file2 (ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/Homo_sapiens/GFF/ref_GRCh38.p12_top_level.gff3.gz).

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want with `awk`:

```
awk '
   FNR==1  { next}
   FNR==NR { chr[FNR]=$1; start[FNR]=$2; end[FNR]=$3; det[FNR]=$4; N=FNR; next}
           { c=$1; p=$2;
             for(i=2;i<=N;i++){
                if((c==chr[i]) && (p>=start[i]) && (p<=end[i])){
                   print c, p, chr[i], start[i], end[i], det[i]
                   next
                }
             }
           }
   ' file2 file1
```

So, firstly notice from the last line that a single invocation of `awk` is processing both files.

Inside the processing, the first line of each file is ignored by checking whether the line number within the current file is 1, and skipping if so:

```
FNR==1  { next}
```

Then, if the record number in the current file is equal to the overall record number that `awk` has processed, it follows we must be reading the first file. So we save each field in an array indexed by the line number and avoid any further processing:

```
FNR==NR { chr[FNR]=$1; start[FNR]=$2; end[FNR]=$3; det[FNR]=$4; N=FNR; next}
```

Otherwise we must be processing the second file. In which case, we loop through all the arrays we saved from the first file to find a matching entry. If we find one in the correct range, we print the bits and pieces you want and move immediately to the next record:

```
{ c=$1; p=$2;
  for(i=2;i<=N;i++){
     if((c==chr[i]) && (p>=start[i]) && (p<=end[i])){
         print c, p, chr[i], start[i], end[i], det[i]
         next
     }
   }
}
```